# ocamlbuild missing from path

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

When I run `ocaml --version` I get `The OCaml toplevel, version 4.07.1`.
But when I try `ocamlbuild --version` I get the following error message:

```
Command 'ocamlbuild' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ocamlbuild
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocamlbuild is not bundled with the OCaml compiler since OCaml 4.03 . You may also want to have a look at [dune](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) as an ocamlbuild alternative.